# Adding optional multiple attribute in Angular component

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component that contains a select element. In some cases I want the "multiple" attribute to be added to the element. Is there a way to add it conditionally?

Answer (score 1):

For a select, conditionally enable the multiple as shown:

```
<md-select [formControl]="myForm" [multiple]="multiEnabled">
```

Your condition to enable or disable the attribute:

```
multiEnabled = false;
```

The above is for a Material select control.

Haven't tried it on other controls.

Comment: Thank you! I bit embarrasing that I did not try that myself. Please don't tell anyone ;-) :-D

Comment: I didn't realize the Multiple attribute for the select component is also an input parameter (after a bit of experimentation). I admit I was surprised as well!